# Boids Flocking System problem with speed calculation interfering with boundaries

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boids

My boundary method and speed method both work perfectly fine separately but when both are called, my boundary method stops working, im following this [guide](https://vanhunteradams.com/Pico/Animal_Movement/Boids-algorithm.html) and my code as far as im aware is perfect in comparison to the sample.

```
    private void Update()
    {
        CheckEdges();

        LimitSpeed();
        MoveBoid();
    }

    // Private
    private void CheckEdges()
    {
        // Top Margin
        if(this.transform.position.y > this.screenMax.y - 1.0f)
        {
            this.velocity.y -= this.turnFactor;
        }

        // Bottom Margin
        if(this.transform.position.y < this.screenMin.y + 1.0f)
        {
            this.velocity.y += this.turnFactor;
        }

        // Left Margin
        if(this.transform.position.x < this.screenMin.x + 1.0f)
        {
            this.velocity.x += this.turnFactor;
        }

        // Right Margin
        if(this.transform.position.x > this.screenMax.x - 1.0f)
        {
            this.velocity.x -= this.turnFactor;
        }
    }

    private void LimitSpeed()
    {
        float speed = Mathf.Sqrt(this.velocity.x * this.velocity.x + this.velocity.y * this.velocity.y);

        if(speed > minSpeed)
        {
            this.velocity.x = (this.velocity.x / speed) * this.minSpeed;
            this.velocity.y = (this.velocity.y / speed) * this.minSpeed;
        }

        if(speed < maxSpeed)
        {
            this.velocity.x = (this.velocity.x / speed) * this.maxSpeed;
            this.velocity.y = (this.velocity.y / speed) * this.maxSpeed;
        }
    }

    private void MoveBoid()
    {
        this.transform.position += (Vector3)this.velocity * Time.deltaTime;
    }
```

Ive refactored and rewrote this code many times but still cannot find a solution, I have triple checked the pseudo-code guide and i cant find what im missing.